# Kernel Density Estimation for bimodal distribution with Python

Tags: python, density-estimation

I have a bimodal distribution for the range [-0.1, 0.1] which can be viewed here:

[image]

I want to train/fit a Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) on the bimodal distribution as shown in the picture and then, given any other distribution say a uniform distribution such as:

```
# a uniform distribution between the same range [-0.1, 0.1]-
u_data = np.random.uniform(low = -0.1, high = 0.1, size = (1782,))
```

I want to be able to use the trained KDE to 'predict' how many of the data points from the given data distribution (say, 'u_data') belong to the target bimodal distribution.

I tried the following code but it doesn't work out:

```
# Here 'a' is the numpy array containing target bimodal distribution.

# Generate random samples-
kde_samples = {}

for kernel in ['tophat', 'gaussian']:
    # Train a kernel on bimodal data distribution 'a'-
    kde = KernelDensity(kernel=kernel, bandwidth=0.2).fit(a.reshape(-1, 1))

    # Try and generate 300 random samples from trained model-
    kde_samples[kernel] = np.exp(kde.sample(300))



# Visualize data distribution using histograms-
plt.hist(a, bins=20, label = 'original distribution')
# sns.distplot(a, kde = True, bins = 20, label = 'original distribution')
plt.hist(kde_samples['gaussian'], bins = 20, label = 'KDE: Gaussian')
plt.hist(kde_samples['tophat'], bins = 20, label = 'KDE: tophat')

plt.title("KDE: Data distribution")
plt.xlabel("weights")
plt.ylabel("frequency")
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.show()
```

This gives the following visualization:

[image: KDE different kernels]

Two things are wrong:

1. The range of the generated samples are wrong!
2. The distribution of generated data is NOT bimodal

How can I therefore: train/fit a Kernel Density Estimation (KDE) on the bimodal distribution and then, given any other distribution (say a uniform or normal distribution) be able to use the trained KDE to 'predict' how many of the data points from the given data distribution belong to the target bimodal distribution.

I am using Python 3.8 and sklearn 0.22.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your bandwidth is too small. Let me demonstrate. Here, I've generated logit-normal samples

[image]

If I fit a KDE with a bandwidth of 0.2,  get the following

[image]

But, if I decrease the bandwidth to 0.02, I get

[image]

Code to generate these plots

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = 1/(1+np.exp(-3*np.random.normal(size = 1000))).reshape(-1,1)

kde = KernelDensity(bandwidth=0.005).fit(x)

X = np.linspace(0,1,101).reshape(-1,1)

plt.hist(x, edgecolor = 'white', bins = 20)

y = kde.sample(1000)

plt.hist(y, color = 'C1', alpha = 0.5, bins = 20, edgecolor = 'white')
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @Arun I've posted the code.

Comment: Is there a way to use a trained KDE estimator to predict whether a given sample data point belongs to the target distribution? For example: `kde.score(np.asarray([0.5, -0.2, 0.44, 10.2]).reshape(-1, 1))          
Out[44]: -2046065.0310518318` This large negative score has very little meaning. Can the new data points or a single data point say np.array([0.56]) be used by the trained KDE to predict whether it belongs to the target distribution or not?

Comment: You could compute the probability of seeing an observation at least as extreme as that observation given your KDE using monte carlo.  I don't think KDE is the right rool for this approach thought.

Comment: can you provide me some resources for what you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: If you have data from other classes, you can use any number of classification algorithms.  If you only have data from a single data generating process, it is difficult to determine if any other given data point comes from that process. You need something to compare against.